# Ошибка при запуске кода с Fmod

Tags: c++, аудио, mp3

Написал тестовую программу для запуска mp3 файла, заголовки и библиотеки положил в папку с проектом, указал компилятору где находятся библиотеки, вроде всё откомпилировалось но при запуске выдаёт ошибку:

> ./Fmod: error while loading shared libraries: libfmod.so.10: cannot open     shared object file: No such file or directory

данная библиотека находится по адресу который прописал при компилировании

```
g++ -L/home/denis/workspace/Fmod main.cpp -lfmod
```

сам код:

```
#include <fmod.hpp>   
#include <stdio.h>   

int main()
{
FMOD_RESULT result;
FMOD::System * system;
FMOD::Sound * sound; 
FMOD::Channel * channel = 0;

result = FMOD::System_Create(&system);

result = system->init(16, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, 0);

result = system->createSound("ns.mp3", FMOD_2D, 0, &sound);

result = system->playSound(sound, 0, false, &channel);

result = channel->setPaused(false);

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Путь указанный в параметре `-L` используется только линкером. Чтобы exe находил библиотеки во время работы их следует поместить в одну из системных папок, либо жестко зашивать путь к библиотеке (`-rpath`).

Answer (score 0):

При запуске установите переменную среды LD_LIBRARY_PATH в значение пути, где- лежат ваши совместно используемые объекты. Типа, так:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/denis/workspace/Fmod"
```

И запускайте в этом сеансе